# Deploy Rails app to Heroku without using git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, deployment

I was doing the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl and after finishing all the chapters, I run the app on my local server and it worked.
Whenever I tried pushing it on github, I get message like "nothing to commit, working directory clean".
Now I want to deploy it on heroku. I have tried but it did not work. Is there another way to deploy to heroku without version control ? Or should I just restart my application from zero ?
How should I go about fixing the git problem ?

Comment: Seems to me like your real problem is that you haven't gotten your files into your git repository. I recommend solving that first....

Comment: "I have tried but it did not work." By itself, that is a useless thing to say: if you want help, you'll need to explain what you did and what the result was in at least a little bit of detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can deploy to heroku without using git.
You can use a plugin heroku push. You can find it at https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push.

Answer (score 0):

There is not another way to deploy to Heroku.

> Git is a powerful decentralized revision control system, and is *the means* for deploying apps to Heroku.

(Emphasis added.)

It's not necessary to restart your application in order to deploy it to Heroku though. You can deploy by initializing a Git repository in your application's directory, "committing" your application in its current state, then "pushing" that commit to Heroku. To begin tracking your application in Git (assuming Git is installed), run the following commands at your command line:

```
$ cd myapp
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .git/
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "my first commit"
Created initial commit 5df2d09: my first commit
 44 files changed, 8393 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README
 create mode 100644 Procfile
 create mode 100644 app/controllers/source_file
...
```

For more information, see Heroku's article, [Deploying with Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).